# Neo4j - get all nodes belonging to an index using Java API

Tags: java, neo4j, graph-databases

Say that I have an index named "user". How do I get all the nodes belonging to that index using Neo4j-Java Api?

I tried the code below

```
val nodeIndex = getNodeIndex("article").get
val nodes = nodeIndex.getGraphDatabase().getAllNodes()
```

But, I got all the nodes present in the db. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use "get" or "query" on the nodeIndex, like:

```
IndexHits<Node> allArticles = nodeIndex.query( "*:*" );
... do stuff ...
allArticles.close();

or

Node myArticle = nodeIndex.get( "name", "MyArticle" ).getSingle();
```

What you did above was to regardless of the index, get the graph database and return all nodes.

Comment: val nodeIndex = getNodeIndex("article").get ;  val articles = nodeIndex.query("*") . Tried this and I got an exception "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: Iterable allArticles = nodeIndex.query( "name", "*" ); --> This thing worked. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: or `nodeIndex.query("*:*")` if you have different keys, please make sure to `close` the `IndexHits` if you don't exhaust it to release resources

Comment: @MichaelHunger How can I query the nodes based on time property using "<" or ">"?